# Material Design WPF, how to get the color to use it on border

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

Everything is in the title.

I'd like to get the color that I choose as primary in my ressources :

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
```

To use it on my border `BorderBrush`:

```
<Border BorderBrush="" BorderThickness="2,0,0,0" Padding="10" >
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
    <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}" BorderThickness="2" Padding="10" Height="50" Width="300">
        <TextBlock Text="Material Design Test" />
    </Border>
```

You can replace `PrimaryHueMidBrush` with `PrimaryHueLightBrush`, or `PrimaryHueDarkBrush`.

You can find more info about configuring your App.xaml at [MaterailDesign documentation](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Getting-Started)